# Docker dealing with images instead of Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

Can someone explain to me why the normal Docker process is to build an image from a Dockerfile and then upload it to a repository, instead of just moving the Dockerfile to and from the repository?

Let's say we have a development laptop and a test server with Docker.

If we build the image, that means uploading and downloading all of the packages inside the Dockerfile. Sometimes this can be very large (e.g. PyTorch > 500MB).

Instead of transporting the large imagefile to and from the server, doesn't it make sense to, perhaps compile the image locally to verify it works, but mostly transport the small Dockerfile and build the image on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This started out as a comment, but it got too long. It is likely to not be a comprehensive answer, but may contain useful information regardless.*

---

Often the Dockerfile will form part of a larger build process, with output files from previous stages being copied into the final image. If you want to host the Dockerfile instead of the final image, you’d also have to host either the (usually temporary) processed files or the entire source repo & build script.

The latter is often done for open source projects, but for convenience pre-built Docker images are also frequently available.

One tidy solution to this problem is to write the entire build process in the Dockerfile using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) (introduced in Docker CE 17.05 & EE 17.06). But even with the complete build process described in a platform-independent manner in a single Dockerfile, the complete source repository must still be provided.

**TL,DR:** Think of a Docker image as a regular binary. It’s convenient to download and install without messing around with source files. You *could* download the source for a C application and build it using the provided Makefile, but why would you if a binary was made available for your system?

Comment: A more accurate analog to an image would be a package i.e. a `rpm` or `deb` and not a statically linked binary (less so for multi-stage though), but otherwise this nails it.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of transporting the large imagefile to and from the server,
>   doesn't it make sense to, perhaps compile the image locally to verify
>   it works, but mostly transport the small Dockerfile and build the
>   image on the server?

Absolutely! You can, for example, set up an [automated build](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds) on Docker Hub which will do just that every time you check in an updated version of your `Dockerfile` to your GitHub repo.

Or you can set up your own build server / CI pipeline accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, one of the reason for building  the images concept and putting into repository is sharing with people too. For example we call Python's out of the box image for performing all python related stuff for a python program to run in Dockerfile. Similarly we could create a custom code(let's take example I did for apache installation with some custom steps(like ports changes and additionally doing some steps) I created its image and then finally put it to my company's repository.

I came to know after few days that may other teams are using it too and now when they are sharing it they need NOT to make any changes simply use my image and they should be done.